# Accumulate to buckets - vectorize

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This question is about MATLAB effective implementation. This is trivial when using for loop!!!

Suppose I have a 2 column vector where the first element of each row is an index and the second is a real number.

I would like to accumulate all the elements that belong to every index.

Ex:

```
V = [1 1; 
     2 3; 
     1 4; 
     2 5 ];
```

Then the result is:

```
R = [1 5; 2 8];
```

The first row is because when adding the 1st and 3rd elements to get 5 and the second is by adding the 2nd and 4th element.

I can assume to know the maximum number of buckets (i.e. the buckets are 1..MAX) and I want the result vector to have MAX rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to complete the task:

```
R = accumarray(V(:,1), V(:,2));
```

If you have a very old version of Matlab you can find [this implementation](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#whist) of weighted histogram useful.